# I'm unable to solve $xy''+y’-x^3=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem with solving this particular type of problem in differential equations. How can I solve this differential equation, what type is it?

$xy''+y'-x^3=0$

I am not sure if it’s solvable because I have been try on g to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Use $u = y'$, then it becomes a linear equation in $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $y' = u$. The original then becomes
\begin{align}
u'(x) + \dfrac{1}{x}u(x) = x^2 &\implies u(x) = e^{-\int \dfrac{1}{x}dx} \left\{ c_1 + \int x^2 e^{\int \dfrac{1}{x}dx}dx \right\}\\
&\implies u(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} \left( c_1 + \dfrac{x^3}{4} \right)\\
&\implies u(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}c_1 + \dfrac{x^3}{4}
\end{align}
and reverting the original substitution we get
\begin{align}
y'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}c_1 + \dfrac{x^3}{4} &\implies y(x) = c_1 \int \dfrac{1}{x}dx + \dfrac{1}{4} \int x^3dx + c_2\\
&\implies y(x) = c_1 \ln x + \dfrac{x^4}{16} + c_2.
\end{align}